# Bash Shell Script Wildcard Nightmare

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

I'm working on a shell script for work that should allow me to find a directory based on a 5 or 6 digit number that a system of ours uses, and copy a file from within that directory. I'd do it manually, but I need to get 3000+ records from around 3TB of available data.

Here's the problem I'm running into. Part of my script is using find, and when I go to run it, the script inserts a '\r' in front of the wildcard that I put in the script. I've tried escaping it with a \, quoting it, but nothing I do will allow me to use the wildcard in this command. I've quoted my code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

export IFS="\n"

cat $1 | while read -r LINE
do
    #Change directory to root of necessary files.
    cd /volume1/Backup/CMS_Data/CLIENT\ DATA\ COPY/

    echo "Current Directory"
    pwd

    #Get directory needed based on current line
    CLAIM="$(find $LINE\*/documents/ -type d)"

    #Change to directory based on claim number.
    echo $CLAIM

done
```

Below is the result that I receive.

```
find: `48668\r*/documents/': No such file or directory
```

I can't find anything about any \r* escape or how to get around it. Any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: First run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all the warnings ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to clean the carriage returns from the input is take advantage of the `read` command's feature that trims leading and trailing whitespace from what it reads. Just redefine `IFS` (basically, the shell's definition of whitespace) to include `\r`, like this:

```
... while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r LINE ...
```

Note that since the definition of `IFS` is a prefix of the `read` command, it applies only to that one command and won't mess other things up (or need to be set back to normal later).

BTW, your redefinition of `IFS` at the beginning is rather problematic, as the backslash isn't treated as an escape in that specific situation, so you've effectively defined `\` and `n` as the whitespace characters. This can have *really* weird effects. I recommend just leaving it alone.

Some other recommendations: `cat` to read the file; it's pointless. Just redirect input, like this:

```
while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r LINE
do
    ...
done <"$1"
```

Also, it's almost always a good idea to put double-quotes around variable references (as I did above for `$2`) to avoid weird parsing artifacts. The same thing goes for `$LINE`. Oh, and I'd also recommend avoiding all-caps variable names; there are a bunch of them with special meanings, and it's easy to accidentally re-use one of those and get weird results. It's much safer to use lower- or mixed-case variable names.

Finally, I recommend always adding an error check to the `cd` command in scripts, since if it fails the rest of the script will run in an unexpected location with maybe bizarre results. Something like this:

```
cd /volume1/Backup/CMS_Data/CLIENT\ DATA\ COPY/ || {
    echo "Error changing directory to CLIENT DATA COPY; giving up" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you're passing as `$1` has `\r\n` newlines. Your `$IFS` is `\n`, so `\r` stays as the final character of `$LINE`.

Use `dos2unix` to convert the file.

Answer (score 0):

There would seem to be multiple ways to fix this.  The easiest way would possibly be to fix the $LINE variable to discard any non-numeric characters.  You can do this by adding the following line before the line starting CLAIM=

```
  LINE=${LINE//[!0-9]//}
```

Depending on your input you may additionally need to change the CLAIM line to  CLAIM="$(find $LINE/*/documents/ -type d)"

An alternative solution would be to change your first line to filter out the carriage returns in the input - you could change it to something like

```
 tr -d "\r" < $1 | while read -r LINE
```